# Apache alias outside of virtual host document route

Tags: apache, alias

I have a situation where my images are on the same level of my document root.

So I need /Users/jwindhall/Sites/gdw/my_app/images (www.example.local/images)

to point to /Users/jwindhall/Sites/gdw/images.

I've been doing:

And the rest...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin example@whatever.com
DocumentRoot "/Users/jwindhall/Sites/gdw/my_app/"
ServerName www.example.local
ServerAlias www.example.local
<Directory "/Users/jwindhall/Sites/gdw/my_app">
   Options All Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
Alias /images /Users/jwindhall/Sites/gdw/images
</VirtualHost>
```

What Am i doing wrong?

Comment: This might be better over on http://serverfault.com.  Or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Alias` needs to be defined in your virtual host (or directly in the server configuration, but that may not be a good idea):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin example@whatever.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/jwindhall/Sites/gdw/my_app/"
    ServerName www.example.local
    ServerAlias www.example.local
    <Directory "/Users/jwindhall/Sites/gdw/my_app">
        Options All Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    Alias /images /Users/jwindhall/Sites/gdw/images
    <Directory "/Users/jwindhall/Sites/gdw/images">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the Alias inside of the VirtualHost.  Also, you don't need a ServerAlias which is identical to ServerName.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin example@whatever.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/jwindhall/Sites/gdw/my_app/"
    ServerName www.example.local
    <Directory "/Users/jwindhall/Sites/gdw/my_app">
       Options All Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    Alias /images /Users/jwindhall/Sites/gdw/images
 </VirtualHost>
```

If that doesn't work, what error are you getting?  And does the apache user have access to the images directory?